# IntelliJ IDEA GroovyDSL support for static star import

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, groovydsl

I have a utility class with an awful lot of methods that I would like to make available in my DSL. Is it possible to describe that behaviour in GDSL without listing every method explicitly?

In other words, I would like to describe in GDSL what with compilation customizer I achieved with this:

```
def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()

def imports = new ImportCustomizer()
imports.addStaticStars(AClassWithAnAwfulLotOfStaticMethods.class.name)

configuration.addCompilationCustomizers(imports)
```

Comment: This is not possible currently

Comment: Thanks, @Dany ! It's good to know, at least, that I did not miss anything in the GDSL documentation.

Comment: @MichalM you can find some docs [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness). For imports can be used `property` keyword but you have to add every static import below star wildcard manually